# How to test whether sample binomial distribution is significantly different from 2 population binomial distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution

I am asking this question for a research problem, not homework, but it's very basic, so let me know if I should add the homework tag.

Let's say that in my sample  of size n = 500, I observe "yes" for a yes/no outcome to occur at a frequency of 0.30.

I know that "yes" for the same yes/no event occurs at a frequency of .50 in Population A and .90 in Population B.

I would like to know:

- whether my sample should be thought of as part of Population A,
  Population B, or as some separate population (i.e. significantly
  different from both A and B) given some level of confidence (say the standard 95%)
- if the procedure would change if Population A's frequency was a perfect complement of Population B's (e.g., .10 and .90, .30 and .70, or .60 and .40). I feel like it would because Pop B would then be the "no" answer for the event, but I'm not sure.

The reason why I am asking this is because my data has been mis-coded where dummy variable codes of, say, 0 were marked as 1 for some unknown number of variables. The flipped codes are uniform within each variable. If, for example,  Variable A is miscoding 0s as 1s, all 500 data points for that variable are miscoded in the same way.

I know what frequencies I *should* have. I can keep data where my observed frequency matches my expected frequency or 1 minus my expected frequency. I have to toss data with frequencies that don't match either of the values or where it is too close to tell - e.g. freq A is 0.52 and freq B is 0.48, and my observed frequency is 0.49.